# I want to change drop down menu text of select tag automatically by javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="weight-unit" class="styled" name="weight-unit" data-placeholder="kg&nbsp;">
                        <option value="" selected></option>
                        <option  class="kg"  value="kg" id="kg" name="kg" >kg</option>
                        <option  class="lbs" value="lbs" id="lbs">lbs</option>
                    </select>
```

When a user clicks a button I want that drop down menu should automatically display lbs without actually going to the drop down menu and selecting it.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried many solutions of making text as selected true using javascript but they have not worked

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a little something like this:

```
document.getElementById("idOfYourButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("weight-unit").value = "lbs";
}, false);
```

That is, use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) to get a reference to your button (assuming it has an id - if not, give it one), then use the [`addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to add a click handler that sets the `.value` property of the select element.

Note that the above code would need to be in a script element after the button, and/or in a document ready/onload handler.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pan4ftn9/

Answer (score 0):

We can use jQuery to set the value of your `select` tag when a particular button is pressed. Let's say you have some `button` with `id` "enterLbs":

```
<button id="enterLbs">Set to lbs.</button>
```

With jQuery, we can select this button and bind an event handler to the button's `click` event. In this case, when the button is clicked, we want to set the value of the `select` (with `id` "weight-unit") to "lbs":

```
$("#enterLbs").click(function() {
    $("#weight-unit").val("lbs");
});
```

So, when the `button` with `id` "enterLbs" is pressed, the `select` with `id` "weight-unit" has its value set to `lbs`. Consider the following working example: http://jsfiddle.net/u2p9npt5/.

If you do not want to use jQuery, you can use JavaScript's `document.getElementById` function to add an event handler to the `button` with `id` "enterLbs```:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enterLbs");
var select = document.getElementById("weight-unit");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    select.value = "lbs";
});
```

Consider this jsfiddle if you would rather not use jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/c51gsp1L/.